# are accessiblity and anti-scrapabality mutually exclusive?

Tags: language-agnostic, user-interface, screen-scraping, usability, accessibility

I want to make a site that is both difficult to screen-scrap and accessible.

Is that an [oxymoron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely. Accessibility relies on tools that parse the underlying code. For example the `table` "summary" attribute, or more common, the "alt" attribute on the `img` tag. In addition, these tools may interpret the code in ways that may not be as straight-forward as this.

So, if a site is accessible is somewhat the same as saying that the underlying code is easily parseable. And, consequently, if it's parseable, it can easily be scraped.

So, yes, you could say it's an oxymoron.